# Does L.A. Noire have parental controls or a family / clean setting?

Tags: la-noire

I'm wondering if there are settings in the game that enable someone to turn down / off explicit content. If so, what settings are available?

Comment: I realize most people ignore ESRB age ratings, but I do still have to say it does stamp the letter **M** on the game cover :P

Comment: @Pyro This information is useful to know because of people who simply want to know if they can play the game safely while children are around.. not explicitly let them play the game. (For example, we do not play Gears of War at my friends house until After his daughter has gone to sleep)

Comment: @James: Oh I hadn't thought of that. Whoops.

Comment: Yeah, this game is definitely not suitable for children, and I don't believe there are any parental controls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game is categorized Level 9 regarding parental control. You can set the level you want on your PS3 to allow or avoid games of higher levels to be launched.
In-game, you cannot deactivate any explicit content (as for a lot of Rockstars games, there wouldn't be a lot still there...).
And as The Annoying Pyro says, always check covers for ESRB rating or other rating depending on location. Here (Europe), the game is rated 18, meaning you should not play before being 18. As James, I wait for my daughter to be in bed to play this kind of games.

Comment: "for a lot of Rockstars games, there wouldn't be a lot still there..." Reminds me of Carmageddon, the 'panic key' was fun: removing all pedestrians (alive or dead) plus the kill counter from screen ;)

Comment: Yesss! Carmageddon! My mother had a stroke seeing me and my brother play this :)